# How to make inappbrowser URL visible in a cordova windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am working on a windows phone app. I am using the cordova framework. One of the functionalities of the app is to allow users make donations. I already have an hosted website for this so what I simply want to do is to allow the app users access this site using inappbrowser. The problem is that windows rejected the app with the following comments:

> The user is prompted for payment information from within the app. Transactions must occur external to the app via a secure (HTTPS) website, or through a hosted control where the address bar is visible to verify the URL and HTTPS security.

So I need to know if there is a way I could make the address bar visible...Any other possible workaround to this problem will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The other workaround is to open the donations site in the native browser i.e. Internet Explorer.

Comment: you cannot make inappbrowser URL visible..you must be open payment URL in native browser like IE,etc...

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. But do you have an idea of how I could open the url in the native browser with the cordova framework?